# Angular: Bind callback function using & and pass-in arguments

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, directive

I have a (simplified) directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
   .directive('myButton', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                callbackFn: '&'
            },
            template: '<button ng-click=ca;;backFn($evenb)'
        }
   });
```

Now, in some parent controller I have defined a callback function:

```
this.myCallback = function ($event) {
    this.doIt($event);
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<my-button callback-fn="page.myCallback()"></my-button>
```

(I'm using things like `bindToController` and `controllerAs`)

The issue is that the `$event` is never passed to `myCallback`, which most likely has to do with how I bind this function (`&`). But on the other hand, inside `myCallback` I would like to use `this`.

Is there some way to fix this ? without doing things like

```
var self = this;
this.myCallback = function ($event) {
     self.doIt($event);
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You haven't completely set up your bindings correctly.  You can pass back arguments from the directive to the parent controller via a key-value map.  According to the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) (emphasis mine):

> `&` or `&attr` - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given `<widget my-attr="count = count + value">` and widget definition of `scope: { localFn:'&myAttr'`}, then isolate scope property `localFn` will point to a function wrapper for the `count = count + value` expression. Often it's desirable **to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example, if the expression is `increment(amount)` then we can specify the amount value by calling the `localFn` as `localFn({amount: 22})`.**

So that means in your consuming HTML you need to add parameters:

```
<my-button callback-fn="page.myCallback(parentEvent)"></my-button>
```

And then in the directive:

```
......
restrict: 'E',
scope: {
            callbackFn: '&'
       },
template: '<button ng-click="ctrl.callbackFn({parentEvent: $event})">Callback</button>'
```

,

Comment: thank you! Struggled for ages with this. Great explanation

Answer (score 1):

According to me you should do it this way :

In your HTML page :

```
<my-button callback-fn="page.myCallback(event)"></my-button>
```

In your directive :

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myButton', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: 'Controller',
            bindToController: true,
            scope: {
                callbackFn: '&'
            },
            template: '<button ng-click=foo($event)'
        }
});

function Controller() {
    this.foo = function (event) {
        this.callbackFn({event: event});
    }   
}
```

But I'm not sur what's the point of your question.